# why does huggingface t5 tokenizer ignore some of the whitespaces?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, sentencepiece

I am using T5 model and tokenizer for a downstream task. I want to add certain whitespaces to the tokenizer like line ending `(\t)` and tab `(\t)`. Adding these tokens work but somehow the tokenizer always ignores the second whitespace. So, it tokenizes the sequence `“\n\n”` as a single line ending and the sequence `"\n\n\n\n"` is tokenized as two line endings and so on. See below to reproduce.

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-large")
tokenizer.add_tokens(["\n"])

tokenizer.encode("\n") # returns [32100, 1] as expected
tokenizer.encode("\n\n") # returns [32100, 1] but expected would be [32100, 32100, 1]
tokenizer.encode("\n\n\n\n") # returns [32100, 32100, 1] but expected would be [32100, 32100, 32100, 32100, 1]
```

what is the reasoning behind this behaviour? Is it a bug or something related to how tokenizer works? I noticed that this only happens for added whitespaces but not for other characters.

Is there way to prevent tokenizer from ignoring the repeated whitespaces?

Comment: related, do you know how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322462/how-to-add-all-standard-special-tokens-to-my-hugging-face-tokenizer-and-model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is explained by how the `tokenize` method in `T5Tokenizer` strips tokens by default. What one can do is adding the token '`\n`' as a special token to the tokenizer. Because the special tokens are never seperated, it works as expected.

It is a bit hacky but seems to work.

```
from tokenizers import AddedToken
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({"additional_special_tokens": [AddedToken("\n")]})
print(tokenizer.special_tokens_map)
```

Then it tokenizes the `'\n'` without skipping any occurences. Note that AddedToken is important because somehow the following does **NOT** work.

```
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({"additional_special_tokens": ["\n"]})
```

## Edit

After spending more time on it, I actually found a way to add it as a normal token without using special tokens. The main reason for the issue is the normalization process that happens behind the scenes even before the tokenization. When you add a new token, you can specify if it should be normalized or not. By setting normalize to False, you avoid the tokenizer from stripping consecutive occurrences of the added token.

```
from tokenizers import AddedToken
tokenizer.add_tokens(AddedToken("\n", normalized=False))
```

You can find more information on this link: https://huggingface.co/course/en/chapter6/4?fw=pt

Comment: related, do you know how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73322462/how-to-add-all-standard-special-tokens-to-my-hugging-face-tokenizer-and-model?

Comment: I read it but did not understand what you are trying to do